# Can't update 'email' and 'profile' scope on google marketplace configuration

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, google-oauth-java-client

In my application I have created a marketplace application which uses

> 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email' 
>   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'

Now as per google will close `userinfo` endpoint. I am trying to change both scope to it's equivalent scope 'email' and 'profile'. Now when I try to refresh user's token with new scope. I am getting below error

> {
>    "error" : "access_denied",
>    "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
>   }

I am using below code to refresh user's token

`new Builder().setTransport(NET_HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JACKSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(googleOAuthService.getServiceClientEmail())
                .setServiceAccountScopes(googleOAuthService.getScopes())
                .setServiceAccountUser(email)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(keyFile);`

I can't change scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` as it will show consent screen again.

I think I need to add 'email' and 'profile' scope in google project marketplace sdk configuration but it gives me error that given scope is not valid.

Anyone please help me how I can fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. The Apps Marketplace configuration currently doesn't recognize these new scopes, and we're working to fix that.

Comment: @EricKoleda any new with this issue?

Comment: No progress I believe. I don't think we plan to actually disable the old scopes anytime soon, so you should be fine for the time being.